# How to get recaptcha to pop up on a window, solve it, then send the g recaptcha response back to the main site?

Tags: python, automation, recaptcha, captcha

I want to be able to retrieve the google recaptcha element on a website, solve it on a different window or server, get the google response token, and send it back. I know this is possible because I have seen multiple programs do this and it works great. Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve this using Python.

If you don't understand what I'm trying to get at, here is a sample: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbgYw4FI6zo Skip to 1:30

In this video, Taskbot, the program, retrieves the recaptcha element from supremenewyork.com, puts that recaptcha on a separate window so the user can solve, then sends that recaptcha response back to supremenewyork.com after it is solved so the user can check out quickly.

I want to be able to integrate this concept into my own program using python.

Also, there is a service that solves captcha for you then returns the captcha token back so processes can continue, it's called anticaptcha recaptcha. This is how they do it:

[Anticaptcha system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzOxQ.png)

I want to be able to complete steps 3, 4, and 5 in the image above with my own code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?